# Would it be possible to dynamically update the collection offset for instancing?

Tags: collections, instances

So I like the idea of collection, but the main problem I have with collection is the lack of a define pivot.  When I use collection for instancing, I need to place all the objects around the origin.

To deal with this problem, I can "use the offset from 3D Cursor" option or I can also move the pivot of a Collection instance.

However, all of these pivot points needs to be reset as soon as I need to move all my collection objects to a new area of the viewport (maybe to make more room to layout more assets).

Then I have to redo the "use the offset from 3D Cursor" or set the pivot of my collection instance over again.   If I have hundreds of collection groups, this becomes a big hassle.  Would it be possible to define a reference object (an Empty for example) instead of "use the offset from 3D Cursor" to dynamically update the reference point every time I need to move the objects in the collection.

Answer (score 2):

The [Collection Utilities](https://blenderartists.org/t/collection-utilities-addon/1229359) addon can batch update collection instance offsets from multiple selected objects.

Have in mind that it do not automatically "live update" center coordinates. It wont update collection instance offsets as you move the object, but it does make the process less painful by allowing to set offset for multiple collections at the same time each from multiple selected objects.

To use it install the addon Collection Utilities from [Blender Artists thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/collection-utilities-addon/1229359) or from [Blender Market](https://blendermarket.com/products/collection-utilities).

After activating it select a bunch of objects in the 3D View, go to the *Objects* menu at the top, *Collections > Set Offset*.

[image]

Selected objects should represent only the "main body" or center of desired collection instance offsets, since their center position relative to scene coordinates will be used to set the instance offset coordinate. Even if there are more objects in said collections those should remain deselected, otherwise they may negatively affect the desired outcome.

There are a myriad of other options to keep collection offset static for certain axis, like say always keep it at Z=0 despite objects being in the air.

Full disclaimer: Shameless self advertising, I created the linked addon.